# how do you append a list to a dictionary value in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So if you have some dictionary like this

```
dictionary={}
dictionary['a']=1
dictionary['a']=2
print(dictionary)
```

this would print {'a':2} and replaces the 1
Is there any way I can add 2 to the key 'a' as a list ?
I know i can do something this like:

```
dictionary['a']=[1,2]
```

but I don't want to do it like this.
Essentially what i am asking is how can i add the new value to my key using a list instead of replacing the previous value.
Appreciate the help!

Comment: You can do `dictionary['a']=[]` and later on `dictionary['a'].append(1)`

Comment: wow, it was so simple, i was overthinking it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
dictionary = {}
dictionary['a'] = []
dictionary['a'].append(1)
dictionary['a'].append(2)
print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth considering using a `defaultdict` if every value in the `dict` is/will be a `list`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

d['a'].append(1)
d['a'].append(2)
```